# CPU Context Info required

Tags: linux, kernel, freebsd, arm

I am running FreeBSD Kernel Version 8.2 on single core ARM. To debug the behavior of some user/application programs running on my system, I need a software that can tell/log information about the trace of all processes running on CPU i.e when/how they are switched and which new process takes the CPU. So, in a nutshell I need CPU Context Info with timestamps.

Is there a way to get CPU context information with timestamp using a software that doesn't require having to recompile the kernel.
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciable.

Comment: [Here is a series of slides from Netflix](https://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/meetbsd2014-performance-analysis) outlining a number of tools to do this for servers.